# can't get jQuery's ajaxComplete working

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, ajax, jquery, prototype-js

I can't get [jQuery's ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) to work.  I'm thinking it's because the ajax call is being initialised by Prototype?  But how can I check when any ajax call This is basically the code I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    function popupInit() {
        jQuery('.popup-window').click(function() {
            // rest of code here
        });
    }
    popupInit();
    jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        console.log( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );
        popupInit();
    });
});
```

I checked in the Chrome sources panel and after an XHR response has finished my function is not called an neither is the `console.log`.

I'm not initiating the ajax call it's coming from a extension for our Magento website:

```
    new Ajax.Request(url, {
        method: 'post',
        onSuccess: function(transport)    {
        if(transport.status == 200)    {

            var data = transport.responseText.evalJSON();

            // Update shipment methods
            if(shipment_methods_found)  {
                shipment_methods.update(data.shipping_method);
            }

            if(update_payments){
                payment_methods.replace(data.payment_method);
            }

            totals.update(data.summary);


        }
    },
    onComplete: function(transport){
        if(transport.status == 200)    {
            if(shipment_methods_found)  {
                $$('dl.shipment-methods input').invoke('observe', 'click', get_separate_save_methods_function(set_methods_url, update_payments));
                $$('dl.shipment-methods input').invoke('observe', 'click', function() {
                    $$('div.onestepcheckout-shipment-method-error').each(function(item) {
                        new Effect.Fade(item);
                    });
                });
            }

            if(update_payments){
                $$('div.payment-methods input[name="payment\[method\]"]').invoke('observe', 'click', get_separate_save_methods_function(set_methods_url));

                $$('div.payment-methods input[name="payment\[method\]"]').invoke('observe', 'click', function() {
                    $$('div.onestepcheckout-payment-method-error').each(function(item) {
                        new Effect.Fade(item);
                    });
                });

                if($RF(form, 'payment[method]') != null)    {
                    try    {
                        var payment_method = $RF(form, 'payment[method]');
                        $('container_payment_method_' + payment_method).show();
                        $('payment_form_' + payment_method).show();
                    } catch(err)    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    parameters: parameters
    });
```

- Is jQuery's ajax complete not working as the ajax request is being
  initialised by prototype?
- How can I check with JavaScript when any
  ajax response is complete?